# Two Arrays with matching index values, Toggle class

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-matching

I'm wanting to toggle class of `show`with an onClick event with a matching `href` and `id` without using any jQuery. I have debugged my JavaScrpit and got the data values and sorted them into their arrays. 
I'm just a little stuck on the remaining bit of actually using the data collected.

### Native JavaScript

```js
function pageToggleMenu() {
 // Find all name and id attributes
 var anchors = document.getElementsByName('link');
 var ids = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');

 // Store href and id values in an array
 var hrefs = [];
 var idsValue = [];

 // Loop through anchors, get href value and store in aray
 for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  hrefs.push(anchors[i].href.slice(22));
 }
 // Loop through ids, get id value and store in aray
 for (var o = 0; o < ids.length; o++) {
  idsValue.push(ids[o].id);
 }

 /* If arrays (hrefs & idsValue) index values match then "anchors" 
           element containing relevant "hrefs" value, toggle class("show")
           with element with matching "idsValue".*/
  
} pageToggleMenu();
```

```html
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <!-- Dashboard -->
                <button class="dash">
                    <i class="icon-dashboard" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Dashboard</button>
                <!-- Explore -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-explore" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Atoms</button>
                <div class="panel nth-explore">
                    <a name="link" href="atoms-global">
                        <p>Global</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Buttons</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Inputs</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Dropdowns</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Automate -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-automate" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Tubs</button>
                <div class="panel nth-automate">
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item One</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item Two</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Publish -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-publish" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Organisms</button>
                <div class="panel nth-publish">
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item One</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item Two</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Analyse -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-analyse" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Mockups</button>
                <div class="panel nth-analyse">
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item One</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item Two</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Settings -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-settings" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Settings</button>
                <div class="panel nth-settings">
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item One</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item Two</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="page-content-wrapper" id="dasboard">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h2>Welcome to Atoms</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius dolores laboriosam saepe fugiat nesciunt simi.</p>
                        <!-- Toggle Button -->
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Atoms: Global -->
        <div class="page-content-wrapper hidden" id="atoms-global">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h2>Global</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius dolores laboriosam saepe fugiat nesciunt corporis.</p>
                        <!-- Toggle Button -->
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont like the idea of matching `href` and `id` but here you go - click on "Global" and the menu will toggle in the end

Please consider not writing `<p>` in your `<a>` elements - it's not a good practice

```js
function toggleClass(element, className) {
  if (element) {
    if (element.classList.contains(className)) {
      element.classList.remove(className);
    } else {
      element.classList.add(className);
    }
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.currentTarget.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' && event.currentTarget.name === 'link') {
    event.preventDefault();
      toggleClass(document.getElementById(event.currentTarget.attributes['href'].value), 'hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <!-- Dashboard -->
                <button class="dash">
                    <i class="icon-dashboard" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Dashboard</button>
                <!-- Explore -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-explore" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Atoms</button>
                <div class="panel nth-explore">
                    <a name="link" href="atoms-global">
                        <p>Global</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Buttons</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Inputs</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Dropdowns</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Automate -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-automate" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Tubs</button>
                <div class="panel nth-automate">
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item One</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item Two</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Publish -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-publish" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Organisms</button>
                <div class="panel nth-publish">
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item One</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item Two</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Analyse -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-analyse" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Mockups</button>
                <div class="panel nth-analyse">
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item One</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item Two</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Settings -->
                <button class="accordion">
                    <i class="icon-settings" aria-hidden="true">
                        <!-- -->
                    </i> Settings</button>
                <div class="panel nth-settings">
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item One</p>
                    </a>
                    <a name="link" href="#">
                        <p>Sub-Item Two</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="page-content-wrapper" id="dasboard">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h2>Welcome to Atoms</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius dolores laboriosam saepe fugiat nesciunt simi.</p>
                        <!-- Toggle Button -->
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Atoms: Global -->
        <div class="page-content-wrapper hidden" id="atoms-global">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h2>Global</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius dolores laboriosam saepe fugiat nesciunt corporis.</p>
                        <!-- Toggle Button -->
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still new to JavaScript and I'm forcing myself to know native JS rather than using jQuery to help me out. This is an old project I've been working on so there are some w3c issues I will be attending to. Thanks so much! - btw I really like your logic you managed to produce. Are there any recommended places to learn native JavaScript online that you used in the past? Thanks again @davis.lucky

Comment: Hi Andrew, I dont know actually :) think any js tutorial + practice would fit. Read about `DOM optimisation` https://www.learnsteps.com/javascript-increase-performance-by-handling-dom-with-care/ and `event delegation` https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate for ex. - it's pretty important